# Expand/Collapse table for Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried expand and collapse operation through jquery! 
But I further want to save the state of the toggle(show or hide)..even when the page is reloaded.
I learned that I would need to use cookie..but I don't know how its done??

HTML:

```
<table width="150px" id="tbl1" class="hvr">
<tr class="header">
    <th style="font-weight:500;">Navigation<span>-</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="dashboard.php">Home</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="slots.php">My Team</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="collection.php">All Pokemons</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="battlenow.php">Battle</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="train.php">Train Pokemon</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="tradecenter.php">My Trade</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="online.php">Online Members</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="members.php">Members</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.header').click(function(){
$(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
$(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function(){});
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/te9cB/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for this.

This is how it works..

Create session cookie:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value');
```

Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('name'); // => "value"
$.cookie('nothing'); // => undefined
```

Read all available cookies:

```
$.cookie(); // => { "name": "value" }
```

Delete cookie:

```
// Returns true when cookie was successfully deleted, otherwise false
$.removeCookie('name'); // => true
$.removeCookie('nothing'); // => false

// Need to use the same attributes (path, domain) as what the cookie was written with
$.cookie('name', 'value', { path: '/' });
// This won't work!
$.removeCookie('name'); // => false
// This will work!
$.removeCookie('name', { path: '/' }); // => true
```

And see this for an [implementation example](http://jsfiddle.net/ErhLu/).